# Message Content Must Be A Non-Empty String MessageEmbed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've encountered this problem when working with discord.js. It seems that when I try to send a MessageEmbed it throws an error at me saying:

```
RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string
```

I've tried turning the MessageEmbed into a string but that doesn't work. Im not sure how to tackle or solve this problem

Here is the code that I have

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
  const testEmbed = new DiscordJS.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Topic')
  if (message.content === '%topic') {
    message.reply({
      content: testEmbed
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `message.reply({embeds: [testEmbed]})`

`{content: ""}` for regular messages only, so it should be:

```
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
const testEmbed = new DiscordJS.MessageEmbed().setTitle('Topic')
if (message.content === '%topic') {
    message.reply({
        embeds: [testEmbed]
    })
   }
})
```